# Scroll automático após carregamento da página(site em wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Olá,

Tenho um sub-menu com Categorias de produtos, e uma página chamada "Produtos" onde listo todos os produtos(post types), separando por categorias em linha.

Meu desejo é que ao clicar em um link do sub-menu, eu carregue a página Produtos e faça o scroll até a categoria respectiva ao link.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que tenha clicado no link para a seção do produto a, basta fazer assim:

```
<a href="www.seusite.com.br/#produtoA">Produto a</a>
```

aquele #produtoA é só o id da seção da página que você quer ir. Isso funciona dentro de uma mesma página e sem recarregar. Se este menu estiver dentro da mesma página que você quer você pode usar só `#produtoA`.

Comment: A ideia seria que a página carregasse no topo, e o usuário pudesse notar o scroll